# Appendix at the end of Chapter

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices

I am writing a book and would like to have appendices at the end of each chapter, for instance appendices at the end of Chapter 2 should look like:

> Appendix 2A Derivation of MMSE Equation
>
> Appendix 2B Proof of ....

Each appendix can contain subsections. In the TOC they should also appear with these titles. And the page headings also should she the title of the appendix. I have looked at the `appendix` package but it does not seem to offer all these capabilities. Any ideas how can I do this?

Comment: So you're comfortable with having these appendices set as `\section` and show up in the ToC formatted as such?

Answer (score 11):

Here's a possible solution in which I assumed that the sections corresponding to appendices will be the last sections of their corresponding chapter. I defined an `\appsection` command to change `\thesection` so as to obtain the required formatting; this command has to be issued before the appendices for a chapter. Using the `etoolbox` package, `\chapter` restores the original meaning of `\thesection`.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\pretocmd{\chapter}{\renewcommand\thesection{\thechapter.\arabic{section}}}{}{}

\newcommand\appsection{%
  \setcounter{section}{0}%
  \renewcommand\thesection{\thechapter.\Alph{section}}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Test Chapter One}
\section{A regular section in chapter one}

\chapter{Test Chapter Two}
\section{A regular section in chapter two}
\appsection
\section{Derivation of MMSE Equation}
\subsection{Some remarks}
\subsection{Preliminary results}
\section{Proof of the main result}
\subsection{Some important consequences}

\chapter{Test Chapter Three}
\section{A regular section in chapter three}
\appsection
\section{Derivation of ABCD Equation}
\subsection{Preliminary results}
\section{Proof of the main result}
\subsection{Some important consequences}
\subsection{Some remarks}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In case hyperref is loaded, the above code has to be slightly changed to

```
\pretocmd{\chapter}{%
  \renewcommand\thesection{\thechapter.\arabic{section}}%
  \renewcommand\theHsection{\thechapter.\arabic{section}}}{}{}

\newcommand\appsection{%
  \setcounter{section}{0}%
  \renewcommand\thesection{\thechapter.\Alph{section}}%
  \renewcommand\theHsection{\thechapter.\Alph{section}}}
```

Comment: When using `hyperref` the modified code doesn't work. It changes, for instance, `2.A Derivation of MMSE Equation` into `2.1 Derivation of MMSE Equation`. Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: @petobens: using both versions (with `thesection` and with `theHsection`) together seems to make it work with `hyperref`.

Comment: The version without `hyperref` works for me while using `hyperref`, but the second does not. The hyperrefs to the appendix is broken, but not to it's subsections.